# Icon when you search for an app in Windows 10 [UWP]

Tags: uwp, windows-10, icons, windows-10-universal, graphical-logo

I have changed the icon for an UWP app that I'm developing and every icon that is shown in the OS looks fine except one.

[image]

I cannot find what assets the platform is taking. This are the assets that I'm using (I preserved the same name than the default template but the image itself were updated):

- LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png
- SplashScreen.scale-200.png
- Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png
- Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png
- Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png
- StoreLogo.scale-100.png
- StoreLogo.scale-200.png
- StoreLogo.scale-400.png
- Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise version 1809 OS build 17763.253

Answer (score 3):

The asset that appears in the Start Menu is reused from the image **Square 44x44 Logo**.

I had a similar problem with this. Microsoft reuses a lot of the assets under the hood and doesn't do a good job telling you which one it's going to use. The style guide for [App Icons and Logos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos) is a good starting point, but I found that making a simple app with recolored assets was the easiest way to test.

I made a simple project and recolored the example assets in Paint.

---

Edit - Feel free to download the project here : https://github.com/Kylaaa/UWP-IconMapper

---

[image: Start Menu Colored Example 1]

After running the app, this is what appeared in my start menu.

[image: Start Menu Colored Example 2]

Comment: I have changed that asset but the change is not reflected on the search list when I look for the app in the start menu. The problem happened in the office's pc but during the weekend I tried to reproduce the problem at home and at the begining seemed to have the same issue (the outdated icon in the search list) but after a while the icon was updated. It was like the menu took some time to refresh the icon.

Comment: For rapid testing, I find that explicitly uninstalling the app is best. It guarantees a fresh pull from the assets.
I read somewhere that your screen resolution also has something to do with which icon Windows uses for the Start Menu, and that lower resolutions or different display zooms also impact which scale amount will be chosen. I'll have to try to find that article again.
Hopefully this helped.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have uninstalled and installed the app again and the problem persists. Also I forgot to mention that it's the third time that I change the icon for the app.

Comment: Finally the icon was updated suddenly after a few days.

Comment: @Wacho, I put together a bunch of sample assets in Paint. Feel free to download the project and experiment with it : https://github.com/Kylaaa/UWP-IconMapper